# Limit application capabilities in IOS to only work with Cell/WiFi data.

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, plist, info.plist

I have searched all over StackOverFlow but did not find any answer on how to use Required Device Capabilities or `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi`.

How do I set values in my application such that the app only works on cellular data/WiFi in the iPhone?

Currently I have set the string WiFi property in the Required Device Capabilities Array according to [iOSDeviceCompatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html).

Is this the correct approach or  should I set `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` `BOOL` to `YES`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation, setting this flag only makes sure that the device attempts to open a Wi-Fi connection. I'm not sure that it will guarantee that your networking will only occur on the Wi-Fi.

There's a class out there by apple called Reachability. `https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html`

There's also a reachability class in AFNetworking 2 `https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking`

I would set your UIRequiresPersistentWiFi flag to YES and then check the reachability class that there is a wi-fi connection available. If not, show an error.

Comment: I have already implemented Reachability class to check whether internet is active or not.

Comment: You can also check which interface is available, not just whether the internet itself is available.

Comment: I created custom method using reachability class and check for internet with BOOL and worked :)